# how to show only last 4 charecters from string remove every thing except last 4 charectors

Tags: android

i have a string which display date and time which store in database on TEXT format like this 
24/02/2014 13:15  i want to display only 13:!5 so how do i subtract string to show only last 4 charecters?

```
String date;
date="24/02/2014 13:15";
```

i want to show only 13:15  time after space so how i will show only 
last   4 or 5 charectors??
my original string is this

```
holder.msgtext.setText("" + msglist.get(position).getMsg());
```

which show display like this

> 24/02/2014 13:15

but i want to show in textview only

> 13:15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String date;
date="24/02/2014 13:15";
String output=date.substring(date.length() - 4)
```

Answer (score 2):

Better to use `.split()` method of String class. split your string by `space`.

```
String[] data = date.split(" ");
Log.e(TAG,"Time: "+data[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
date = "24/02/2014 13:15";
date = date.substring(date.length() - 4, date.length());
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use **date format** for this

Try this

```
SimpleDateFormat form = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
String date = "24/02/2014 13:15";
Date date1 = null;
try {
   date1 = form.parse(date);
     } catch (ParseException e) {
e.printStackTrace();

}
SimpleDateFormat postFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
String timefromdate = postFormater.format(date1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way,

```
String str = "24/02/2014 13:15"; 
str = str.substring( str.lastIndexOf( " " ) + 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use java.util.DateFormat

```
private void test() throws ParseException
{
    DateFormat fromFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
    fromFormat.setLenient(false);
    DateFormat toFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    toFormat.setLenient(false);

    String dateStr = "24/02/2014 13:15";
    Date date = fromFormat.parse(dateStr);
    System.out.println(toFormat.format(date));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
String date="24/02/2014 13:15";

String show = date.substring(date.charAt(date.length()-5==' ')?date.length()-4:date.length()-5);
```

Answer (score -1):

i think it's 5 charcter

```
date = "24/02/2014 13:15";
date = date.substring(date.length() - 5, date.length());
System.out.print(date);
```

Comment: what if date = "24/02/2014 3:15";

solution will be wrong.

Comment: yes that is okay but other answer giving wrong result.

Comment: yes..still 1 has given crrt ans with split method.we should upvote crrt ans instead ignoring it and giving own ans.